# How to use TF Adam to optimize multiple outputs from the same neural-network; but with a varying linear transformation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, time-series, gradient-descent

So this is a tough question to ask, as i dont have examples of code.
I have a task where the same neural network predicts a time-series characteristic(say a single sigmoid activation) for single time period ahead. So you have several areas with information at time t say A(t),B(t),C(t) -- this same neural network will take in some past information and give you various outputs Y(A;t),Y(B;t).Y(C;t).

You want to take the time based outputs of this neural network for various inputs, and at each output apply a time-varying but known linear transformation. At this point you have a collection of outputs depending on the network parameters, time-dependent inputs and  linear transformations.

After this you basically you want to collect a number of these outputs over a period of a month. You then compute a value X based on all of these outputs (after their linear transformation) for that month.

I now want to use ADAM to optimize the weights of this neural network(the same network is used each time). I have something that depends on the outputs of a lot of different fixed neural network inputs, and a lot of different fixed linear transformations.

So i am not sure how to use tensorflow ADAM to change the weights, if you can simply use the model.output or predict in a custom version of the optimizer and it will understand this is a function of the weights.

Sorry if this is hard to understand, i am finding it hard to explain and i dont have code for it as that would make the question redundant.